# how to sort a file in ascending order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sorting

I have the following code to join the file and trying to sort the file in ascending order before writing the result into the final .txt file. But it is showing string object has no attribute.

```
temp_list = ''
with open('temp.txt') as f:
out = [x for x in f.read().split("\n") if x.strip() != ""] 
for line1, line2 in list(zip(out, out[1:]))[::2]:
    line1 = line1 + ';'
    line2 = line2.split(' ')
    line = ''
    for x in range(1,len(line2)):
        line = line + line2[x] + ' '
    line = line[:-1] + '.' 
    temp_list += " ".join([line1, line]) + '\n'
    temp_list.sort()

with open('new.txt' , 'w') as file:
file.write(temp_list)
```

temp.txt

```
line1 Ron likes apple; mango
line5 Ana likes lyche; apple
line21 Tyson likes football; VolleyBall
line6 Mike likes singing; dancing
line245 Stephen likes playing; sleeping
line95 Rose likes dancing; singing
```

The order of the lines should be like

```
line1
line5
line6
line21
line95
line245
```

but not like

```
line1
line21
line245
line5
line6
line95
```

Any help would be appreciated ..Thank you

Comment: Do all of your lines start with "Line"?

Comment: @Hai Vu, Yeah..Each Line starts with line

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this way:

```
with open('temo.txt','r') as f:
    l1 = [l.lstrip('line').split(' ',1) for l in f.readlines()]
    l2 = sorted([[int(a),b.strip()] for a,b in l1])
    for s in l2:
        print(f"line{s[0]} {s[1]}")
```

Output:

```
line1 Ron likes apple; mango
line5 Ana likes lyche; apple
line6 Mike likes singing; dancing
line21 Tyson likes football; VolleyBall
line95 Rose likes dancing; singing
line245 Stephen likes playing; sleeping
```

For the print error mentioned in the comments, try this:

```
print("line{} {}".format(s[0],s[1]))
```

Comment: print statement is not working in linux. However, the code works in others. I do not want to strip the word line how will that work?

Comment: Any idea about syntax for print statement in Linux cause it not not allowing "print()" this format

Comment: @sri Fixed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open("temp.txt", "r") as infile, open("new.txt", "w") as outfile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    if not lines[-1].endswith("\n"):
        lines[-1] = lines[-1] + "\n"
    lines.sort(key=lambda x:int(re.findall(r"^[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)$", x.split()[0])[0]))
    outfile.writelines(lines)
```

You can try this using `re`.If the format is fixed, this will work.

`Input text`

`Line1 Ron likes apple; mango
line5 Ana likes lyche; apple
line21 Tyson play football; VolleyBall
line6 ..........................
line245 .......................
line95 ............
line11 .........
line12 ..........
line20 ..........`

`Output text`

`Line1 Ron likes apple; mango
line5 Ana likes lyche; apple
line6 ..........................
line11 .........
line12 ..........
line20 ..........
line21 Tyson play football; VolleyBall
line95 ............
line245 .......................`

Comment: It is throwing an error saying "List Index out of range"

Comment: I have the same format in every line. I would like to sort the file based on the numerical value after line

Comment: I modified the question... Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real solution, but a workaround. I would save all lines in a dictionary and then just write this few lines:

```
def sort_lines(your_dictionary):
    temp_list = []
    for i in range (1, len(your_dictionary)+1):
        temp_list.append(your_dictionary[i])
    return temp_list
```

If your not sure if you have every number from 1 to the highest just change it a little bit:

```
def sort_lines(your_dictionary):
    temp_list = []
    for i in range (1, len(your_dictionary)+1):
        try:
            temp_list.append(your_dictionary[i])
        except:
            pass
    return temp_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe use sorted

```
    temp = [
        "Line1 Ron likes apple; mango",
        "line5 Ana likes lyche; apple",
        "line21 Tyson play football; VolleyBall",
        "line6 ..........................",
        "line245 .......................",
        "line95 ............",
    ]


    def sort_fn(a):
        idx = a.find(" ")
        key_a = int(a[4:idx])
        return key_a

    sort = sorted(temp, key=sort_fn)
    print(sort)
```